# Tkinter display goes outside of the screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When creating A Gui with Tkinter using lots of images cause the window to be larger than the screen how do I stop this?
when running the code the tkinter window displays like this:

[screen shot of tkinter window that is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VoUB.png)

```
    import time
from tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
#setting frames
        self.master=master
        speeddisp=Frame(master)
        speeddisp.grid(row=1, column=2)
        clockdisp=Frame(master)
        clockdisp.grid(row=0,column=0)
        indicatorhazard=Frame(master)
        indicatorhazard.grid(row=0, column=2)
        datedisp=Frame(master)
        datedisp.grid(row=0, column=3)
        lightdisp=Frame(master)
        lightdisp.grid(row=1,column=0)
        fandisp=Frame(master)
        fandisp.grid(row=1,column=0)
        tempdisp=Frame(master)
        tempdisp.grid(row=3,column=2)
#setting photos in Photoimage class from TK
        self.left_indicator_on_img=PhotoImage(file="left on.gif")
        self.left_indicator_off_img=PhotoImage(file="left off.gif")
        self.right_indicator_on_img=PhotoImage(file="right on.gif")
        self.right_indicator_off_img=PhotoImage(file="right off.gif")
        self.hazard_off_img=PhotoImage(file="hazard off.gif")
        self.hazard_on_img=PhotoImage(file="hazard on.gif")
        self.light_on_img=PhotoImage(file="light on.gif")
        self.light_off_img=PhotoImage(file="light off.gif")
        self.fan_on_img=PhotoImage(file="fanimg on.gif")
        self.fan_off_img=PhotoImage(file="fanimg off.gif")
#defining and placing labels                        
        self.speedlbl=Label(speeddisp, text=('00.00MPH'), font=("Helvetica", 110))
        self.speedlbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.clocklbl=Label(clockdisp, text=(time.gmtime()[3],":",time.gmtime()[4]))
        self.clocklbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.leftindicator=Label(indicatorhazard,image=self.left_indicator_off_img)
        self.leftindicator.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.rightindicator=Label(indicatorhazard,image=self.right_indicator_off_img)
        self.rightindicator.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.hazardindicator=Label(indicatorhazard,image=self.hazard_off_img)
        self.hazardindicator.grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.datedisplay=Label(datedisp, text=(time.gmtime()[2],"/",time.gmtime()[1],"/",time.gmtime()[0]))
        self.datedisplay.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.lights=Button(lightdisp, image=self.light_off_img)
        self.lights.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.fanimg=Label(fandisp, image=self.fan_off_img)
        self.fanimg.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.temptxt=Label(tempdisp,text='00.00c', font=("Helvetica", 50))
        self.temptxt.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when the image is too large to fit? Refuse to display it? Shrink the image? Crop the image? scroll the image? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should either crop the image using a photo editor so that the image is small enough to fit inside the window or run this code in python to make the tkinter window bigger:

```
self.master.geometry("1000x1000")
```

inside

```
__init__
```

and the

```
"1000x1000"
```

is x pixels by y pixels.